# Code security on client machine with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ssl

I know there is no way to hide code from client once browsers has downloaded front end files. But I heard that one can also debug the javascript code, add breakpoints, skip the code lines (security checks mostly) and manipulate service calls as they wish.

The project I'm working on is developed in AngularJS and uses SSL certificate for service calls, but other then that how can I add security on client side to save my code from being manipulated?

Comment: There is no "security" on the client side. Don't do "secure" things on the client, period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. You can make it a bit more difficult by employing techniques such as [minifyng](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources), but the only concrete solution is to validate ALL calls on the backend and assume the frontend is not to be trusted.

If your security is being handled by the frontend alone, you don't have security at all. The backend is where it has to happen.

That's not to say you should leave frontend security out altogether though - the average user will be kept at bay by frontend measures. But just remember that not all users are average, and the frontend can never be secure.

Comment: yes its true...minifying is only the solution to secure our code on client side

Comment: Well no, it won't secure your code, it will just obfuscate it. There are tools out there to undo minification.

Comment: but how do I stop them from using my service calls?  They can do that too cant they?

Comment: You can't. Thats why you need to handle the security and validation on the backend too.